# Disabled Lockscreen on Ubuntu accidently, How to renable it?

Tags: screen, lock

Okay,so few months back I read a post somewhere, dont remember where but it was on how to disable the lock screen. Now that I disable whenever the monitor switches off the system hangs. I remember Editing using gedit to do that. How do I re enable Lockscreen? I'm not talking about just removing it from the menu, im talking about disabling it completely. How do I re enable it?

Comment: When you make amends in the menu, it usually changes something in a file. If you deleted something in a file that doesn't sound good.

Can you find out which file you changed, perhaps it's in recently used files in gedit?

Comment: The problem is I made a while ago. And as far as I remember I didn't delete anything. I wrote something in the file like
[Disable Lock Screen]
some lines 

Instead of [Re-enable Lock screen] 
But I'm really not sure

Comment: Hmmm, you could start by locking the screen using Ctrl+Alt+L and check it's not a problem with suspend or sleep. Obviously save your work.

Comment: The next thing I would do is to have a look at your log files, if something is throwing an error that would be nice.

Comment: As I said, I didn't remove it from the menu. I Completely disabled it. So Ctrl + Alt + L doesn't work. But in power settings it locks screen after 10 minutes so the screen hangs. I have currently changed it to Never for now so that It doesnt hang but I want to get back the lock screen feature.

Comment: /var/log/messages, 
/var/log/syslog, 
/var/log/kern.log. 

they look scary, sometimes it's obvious spotting an error

Comment: The Logs are of too recent changes. I made those changes a while ago.

Comment: I've added an answer does it work?

Comment: I was being lazy and I copied the names off the website I'll take a look at mine.

Comment: try dmesg instead of messages

Comment: allright, my system hung and this is the line from syslog 

Aug  4 22:17:01 varun-K52F CRON[4216]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

thats is the only thing i could find for that time because that is when my system hung. dmesg doesn't have todays logs and kern skips from 22:05 to 22:20

Comment: the screen lock program is no acpi it is actually lightdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joshua 
How stupid of me. I had just turned lock screen off from Ubuntu tweak. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/default/acpi-support deals with this sort of function. Perhaps LOCK_SCREEN=true is commented out with the #

```
# Set the following to "platform" if you want to use ACPI to shut down
# your machine on hibernation
HIBERNATE_MODE=shutdown

# Comment this out to disable screen locking on resume
LOCK_SCREEN=true

# Uncomment this line to have DMA disabled before suspend and reenabled
# afterwards
# DISABLE_DMA=true
```

If it is so, try uncommenting it and it might fix your problem, you might have to restart your computer too I should add.

Comment: Nope It was without the #. Just as you mentioned in the comment

Comment: Hmmm that's a shame

Comment: http://blog.projectz.me/2012/06/25/disable-the-lock-screen-and-screen-blank-on-ubuntu-12-04/  any help?

Comment: I already tried that. Since that command line is for Disabling it,

I used this
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true

Whereas in the post they asked us to use "false"

Comment: if you can cause the system to hang, by making the screen lock you might see an error in one of the files I mentioned ^^^^ up there

Comment: Well I dont have a file "messages" . Well you know what I'll make my pc hang and look into the files again

Comment: does lightdm ring any bells?

Comment: Well,hold on
I made edits to remove white does in lightdm. That was made when I installed ubuntu. Once i install ubuntustudio lightdm theme from synaptic. That didn't work. So i didn't bother. Now im removing it and restarting my pc. I dont think Lightdm has to do anythig with this. How do I add a picture to this comment?

Comment: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8282/7712496550_28a97639ef_b.jpg

as you can see,I cant move the screen lock button left or right since its completely disabled

Comment: Ouch... I'll have a think. You need to find the connection that button makes normally.

Comment: can you "sudo apt-get install lightdm" what login screen do you have?

Comment: The lightdm and login screen are Ubuntu defaults. except for the white dots. http://goo.gl/TdmVI